How to config webhook in console application?
I have console application (in .net 5) that runs as window service with a lots of class libraries in the same solution:
Commons.cs proj (Class library)
BusinnesLogic.csproj (Class library).
and more...
Service.csproj (Console Application runs on .net 5).
for example, my service project that run the app:
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.AddMemoryCache();
                }).UseWindowsService();
    }


I need and also want to add webhook implementation that will listen to certain port and when receive an http message the webhook will handle it in my way.
how should I do it?
I can't find any solution.

Your best choice is to add another "ASP.NET Core Web API" project, where you can define your Web Hook as a Controller or as a minimal API. If you reference your business layer projects, you can also use your common business logic in that web api project.
